# How to only enable ctrl+scroll but disable cmd+scroll to zoom on MacOS VSCode?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Currently, the MacOS VSCode only allow CtrlCmd+scroll to zoom. This makes cmd+scroll and ctrl+scroll both works, puting much more probability for me to mis-operation when I use the magic mouse.

Is there any method to only enable ctrl+scroll but disable cmd+scroll to zoom?